# Checar clientes usando curl python

Tags: python-3.x

Eu tenho uma lista em .txt no formato email|senha dos meus clientes e quero verificar a integridade de alguns cadastros. Eu queria criar uma variável que pegasse linha por linha do txt e mudasse no payload do curl o email e a senha. Por exemplo, ele lesse o .txt e testa-se os cadastros um por um, linha por linha, de forma automática. exemplo:

file.txt

```
cliente1@gmail.com|123
cliente2@gmail.com|456
cliente3@gmail.com|789
```

No payload do curl ficara assim(um exemplo):

```
payload = "username=variavel1&password=variavel2&clientVersion=2.4.9-undefined"
```

A variavel1 seria o email, já a variavel 2 a senha do cliente, no caso do primeiro cliente ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
payload = "username=cliente1@gmail.com&password=123&clientVersion=2.4.9-undefined"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as fd:
    for linha in fd.readlines():
        user, pwd = linha.strip().split('|')
        payload = "username={}&password={}&clientVersion=2.4.9-undefined".format(user, pwd)
        print(payload)
```